# TSql130Parser seems not to recognize hints

Tags: .net, sql-server-2016, scriptdom

I created the following console application with a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll:

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Product OPTION(USE HINT('ENABLE_PARALLEL_PLAN_PREFERENCE'))"
        Dim parser As New TSql130Parser(False)
        Dim errors As Collections.Generic.IList(Of ParseError)
        Dim script As TSqlScript = parser.Parse(New StringReader(sql), errors)
        Console.WriteLine(errors(0).Message)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Running this console application produces the following output:

```
Incorrect syntax near HINT.
```

But this SQL fragment is correctly parsed in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

It seems therefore, that TSql130Parser does not work correctly. 
Do you know if there is a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the 14.0 version or later of `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll` in order for the `TSql130Parser` to recognize the newer hint. The latest 14.0 version is 14.0.3811.1 as of this writing and is available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/140.3881.1). There is also a [15.0 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/150.4200.1) version available, which supports SQL Server 2019 (currently in CTP) and the older TSqlParsers with the latest features.